# Cant make field unique!

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1062

Can you not have more than 2 unique fields in a table or am i doing something wrong here?

I have 1 unique key for username and i want it for email too but i get

`#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'`

```
alter table users
add unique (email)
```

Tbl:

```
`id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`registered` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's telling you you already have non-unique entries in the email field, namely, the value '' (empty string)

Answer (score 2):

You have the same value (i.e. `''`) in the `email` column on more than one row.  That means you can't put a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column.

You could make the column nullable, then update the value to NULL where it's currently `''`, and then create a `UNIQUE` constraint on it, because `UNIQUE` permits nulls.

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY email VARCHAR(100);

UPDATE users SET email = NULL WHERE email = '';

ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE KEY (email);
```

BTW, why do you have the value `''` in the email column?  That's not a valid email address.

Comment: I dunno -- your average points per answer is 36.22.  My average points per answer is 30.51.

Answer (score 1):

This means that (at least) 2 records have an empty email.

Remember: NULL != ''

To find them:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email= '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one unique field.

I think the error is complaining about the data in the email field. (I think you have more than one row with a value of '' )

Answer (score 0):

No value is also considered unique, so two email rows with nothing are duplicate, if they are to be judged by a unique standard.